Saving form data failed：TemplateDoesNotExist at /article/1/comment article/comment_form.html
# views.py:
class CommentAddView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = CommentForm  
    model = Comment

  
    def form_valid(self, form):

        comment = form.save(commit=False)

        comment.article_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        print(type(comment.article_id))
        comment.user = self.request.user
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        form.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('article:detail',args=[self.kwargs['pk']])

# forms.py:
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['body','user']
#models.py:
class Comment(BaseModel):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('user.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField('content', help_text='content')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'comment'
        verbose_name = 'coment'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article.title

#article_detail.html:
<v-form action="{% url 'article:comment_add' article.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <v-textarea
            height="100px"
            class="mx-2"
            name="body"
            placeholder="Please enter"
        >

        </v-textarea>
        <div class="d-flex justify-end">
        <v-btn
                color="primary"
                small
                type="submit"
                class="mr-7 mb-2"
        >Get it!</v-btn>
        </div>
    </v-form>

This is article details page similar to blog, I want add a comment function, but is will report a different error.
I'm trying to write - comment_form.html, but It's not written in the video tutorial.
I also tried adding a 'user' to the field list.
But is doesn't work, you can't save the comment data like in the video.
When I translate field=['body'] to field=['body','user'],the error translated 'TypeError at /article/1/comment
fromisoformat: argument must be str' to 'TemplateDoesNotExist at /article/1/comment article/comment_form.html'.
So I think there's something else going on.

This code does not mention fromisoformat, so the error must be happening inside other code that you have not shown us.  It's very hard to help when you do not show us the code that actually has the error.

Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

I think it might be a 'models.py' problem.Take a look at my entire medels.py

This error will change if I change the field in form.py
